# Triangle of for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I am working on an assignment and I understand how to do the first part of the assignment but not the second.

Problem:

> Write a program that ask the user to enter the size of a triangle (1 to 50), then print the triangle by printing a series of lines consisting of asterisks.  The first line will have 1 asterisk, the next two will have two and so on, with each line having one more asterisk than the previous line up to the number entered by the user.  On the next line print one less asterisk and continue by decreasing the number of asterisk by 1 for each successive line until any one asterisk is printed.

I can make the program print up ward however I don't know how to make it print downward. My professor says to use for loops.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CS123Ass5ID5189 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size;
        System.out.println("Enter Triangle size");
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        size = key.nextInt();

        System.out.println(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int f = 0; f < i; f++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("*");

        }
        for (int i = 0; i > size; i--) {
            for (int f = 0; f > i; f--) {
                System.out.println("*");
            }
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Supposed to look something like

```
 *
 **
 ***
 **
 *
```

Comment: Your second outer loop won't be entered at all unless size is negative `for (int i=0; i>size;`

Comment: Yes, change it to `<` in both loops, and in the inner loop just use `print`, not `println`.

Comment: i made the change and now i'm just getting asterisks printing into infinity

Comment: You can use either `>` or `<` in the for loops as long as the total count is the same. (I can count from 1 to 100 or from 100 to 1, but either way, I get 100 numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is almost there. You just need the second outer loop to count down from `size` to zero in the outer loop, and do the same thing.

```
for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

So the first loop goes from 0 to size, and this loop goes from (size - 1) to 0.

```
for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    // This section is exactly the same as in the first loop
    for (int f = 0; f < i; f++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("*");
}
```

**Edit**

To limit the input number to 50, check it in another loop. While the user has entered an invalid number, tell them, and ask for another one. Add this just after you get the initial number:

```
while (size < 0 || size > 50)
{
    System.out.print("Size must be between 0 and 50. Try again: ");
    size = key.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but now i'm getting it to count up until the number i select but it continuously prints into infinity after that. it doesn't decrease in number

Comment: Did you fix the inner loop?

Comment: Yay, a whole bunch of identical answers, and mine was chosen!

Comment: Oh i see! thank you so much Andrew. one last question. How do i limit the integer to 50 when the user inputs a number as per what the problem states?

Comment: Check the value of size, just after you call `size = key.nextInt()`, and make sure it is valid. You can check in a loop, until they put a valid number in. See the edit above.

Comment: @AustinHarlan - Please see my answer for the while loop

Comment: I wish I had made more use of Stack Overflow when I was in first year at University :D

Answer (score 0):

For loops can begin at any value, not just zero. This allows you to start at `size` and decrement all the way down to zero.

[Here](http://ideone.com/22uYgG) is an example of what you are looking for. (It links to an online executable to demonstrate the code below.)

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int size = 10;

        System.out.println(size);

        for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++)
        {
            for (int f=0; f<i; f++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("*");
        }

        for (int i=size-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            for (int f=i; f>0; f--)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Your second inner for loop should have `System.out.print` not `System.out.println` to keep all the asterisks on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is wrong, it should be for `i>0`. Also, start at 1, not 0 and print like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    for (int f = 0; f < i; f++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
for (int i = size-1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int f = 0; f < i; f++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Your inner loop should still be counting up to the value of `i`. This should do what you need.

Comment: ok I'm almost there however when the program counts down for the second half of the triangle it now counts down vertically. instead of horizontally like the rest of the triangle.  any ideas???

Comment: One more time: make sure your inner loops both use `print`, not `println`.

Comment: @AustinHarlan Not sure what you mean by count down vertically? You mean it prints 1 asterisk per line? Check again if you would, I just updated 2nd loop to `print` instead of `println`. Forgot to change it before.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i was saying!  thank you for the help. I experimented around with the above suggestions and that fixed it. Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop looks fine, but look at the second loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i > size; i--) {
    for (int f = 0; f > i; f--) {
        System.out.println("*");
```

If size is greater than 0, the outer for-loop won't be entered. Fix that by setting `i = size - 1`, then loop until `i > 0` and `i--` to decrease `i` in each loop.

The inner for loop has a similar problem, it should be the *exact same* and the previous inner loop. Also *exact same* in the usage of `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`. Otherwise, the triangle will print vertically for the bottom half.

---

FWIW - It's easier to read if you make small methods to clearly show your intention.

```
private static void printStarLine(int howManyStars) {
    for (int i = 0; i < howManyStars; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    int size = 3; // some number in the range 1-50
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter Triangle size (1-50)");
        size = key.nextInt();
    } while (size < 1 || size > 50);

    for (int stars = 1; stars < size; stars++) {
        printStarLine(stars);
    }

    printStarLine(size);

    for (int stars = size - 1; stars > 0; stars--) {
        printStarLine(stars);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)  
{  
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++)  
    {  
        System.out.print("*");  
    }  
    System.out.println();  
}  
for(i=n; i>=1; i--)  
{  
    for(j=1; j<i; j++)  
    {  
       System.out.print("*");  
    }  
    System.out.println();  
}
```

this works